# (Java)wrong date calculation output

Tags: java, date

This is my first post here. My apologies for my grammar.
Question
From this code, I want to find how many weekend day and weekday from start date to end date like 12/03/2014 to 23/03/2014. When input is xx/xx/2015 to xx/xx-2015. It doesn't has any problems but if input is xx/xx/2014 to xx/xx/2014,it will show wrong date.

Example

12/03/2014 to 23/03/2014

output

Tue 12 March: wrong date

Sat 23 March: wrong date

Example2

11/03/2015 to 22/03/2015

Wed 11 March : ok

Sun 22 March : ok

I sent this to my friend and he said it runs fine. Is it because jdk version? 
I use java jdk1.8.0_40 but my friend is jdk1.8.0_31.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class getDate
{
 public String S_duration;
 public String E_duration;
 
 public getDate()
 {}
 public void Setstart(String start)
 {
  S_duration=start;
  System.out.println("Start duration: "+S_duration);
  
 }
 public void Setend(String end)
 {
  E_duration=end;
  System.out.println("End duration: "+E_duration);
  
 
 }
 public void date_cal()throws Exception
 { 
  int count1=0;
  int count2=0;
  boolean i=false;
 
  SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  
 
  Date Sdate = parser.parse(S_duration);
  Date Edate = parser.parse(E_duration); 
  
  Calendar s = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  Calendar e = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  s.setTime(Sdate);
  e.setTime(Edate);
  Date SD=s.getTime();
  Date ED=e.getTime();
  
  //System.out.println("\nStart Duration(DD/MM/YYYY): "+s.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+"/"+s.get(Calendar.DATE));
  System.out.println("\nStart Duration(DD/MM/YYYY): "+SD+"/"+s.get(Calendar.YEAR));
  System.out.println("\nEnd Duration(DD/MM/YYYY): "+ED+"/"+e.get(Calendar.YEAR));
  
  while (!i)
  {
     int day = s.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
     if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
    
     count1++;
     System.out.println("count1: "+count1);
     }
     else
     {
      count2++;
      System.out.println("count2 "+count2);
     }
     if(s.equals(e))
     {
      i=true;
     }

      
     s.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
  }
  
  System.out.println("\nMon-Fri: "+count2);
  System.out.println("\nSat-Sun: "+count1);
  System.out.println("\n*************************************************************************");
 }

}

public class Datecalculation {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
  String d1,d2;
  int mode=0;
   getDate datecal=new getDate();
  
  while(mode==0)
  {
  System.out.println("\nPlease enter Start Duration(DD/MM/YYYY):");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);      
  d1=in.nextLine();
  
  datecal.Setstart(d1);
  System.out.println("\nPlease enter End Duration(DD/MM/YYYY):"); 
  Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);      
  d2=in2.nextLine();
  
  datecal.Setend(d2);
  datecal.date_cal();
  System.out.println("\nExit?(YES=1/NO=0)");
  mode=in.nextInt();
  }
  
 }
}
```

Comment: what's the output you're getting when setting dates 12/03/2014 to 23/03/2014?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK usually doesn't create such errors.
I run it on a 1.8.0_40 (the same you're having problems) and it produce correct results:

```
Mon-Fri: 8

Sat-Sun: 4
```